# Regex function to find @ mentions does not work anymore

Tags: ios, regex, swift, string

Xcode 8.3.3

I wrote a regex method to get all mentions of a string.

```
func getMentions() -> [String] {
    let pattern = "\\B@[A-Za-z0-9]+"
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpression.Options(rawValue: 0))
        let nsstr = self as NSString
        let all = NSRange(location: 0, length: nsstr.length)
        var matches : [String] = [String]()
        regex.enumerateMatches(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: all) {
            (result : NSTextCheckingResult?, _, _) in
            if let r = result {
                let result = nsstr.substring(with: r.range) as String
                matches.append(result)
            }
        }
        Log.info(matches)
        return matches
    } catch {
        return []
    }
}
```

This used to work just fine. 
However, when I run this, I get empty matches. Did something get updated just now?

I've also tried this:

`let pattern = "\\B@[A-Za-z0-9]+\\b"`

Comment: your code works fine if this method is in a String extension context

Comment: Can you add a test data and the expected result for it?